How to run projects sequentially but with tests in parallel?
I have one test where a user is logged in and modifies saved data.
This test should never be executed twice at the same time but it might run parallel to all other test in the suite (=all test files within the test directory) without a problem.
So when running all tests with multiple workers for one project everything's fine. But running all tests for all projects with multiple workers is not possible.
While running everything with just one worker would be a solution, I wonder if there was the alternative and probably remarkably faster way to run all projects sequentially one after the other with multiple workers?

From the documentation, it should be possible. The test that should not be executed can be made part of a separate projects
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'setup',
      testMatch: '**/*.setup.ts',
    },
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] },
      dependencies: ['setup'],
    },
    {
      name: 'firefox',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Firefox'] },
      dependencies: ['setup'],
    },
    {
      name: 'webkit',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Safari'] },
      dependencies: ['setup'],
    },
  ],
});


Thanks for the answer! I assume you meant in my case to make one project depend on the next, so that they would be executed in a row? The docs say *"If the tests from a dependency fails then the tests that rely on this project will not be run."` Unfortunately I didn't find anything on if this can be disabled


So when running all tests with multiple workers for one project everything's fine.  But running all tests for all projects with multiple workers is not possible.

If you can make that test part of a separate project and even don't use dependancies, you should not face issues with multiple workers, given that in a project single worker executing only available test

I'm not sure there's a misunderstanding. The 'special' test should not only be executed once, but for all existing projects (currently 5 for different browsers) While I could seperate the test into five additional projects - is it possible to set the number of workers not only globally but on a project level?


In that case, why would the test run multiple times even if you use various workers? It should not have any impact as per my understanding
No workers are set config level and not possible to set at project level as far as I know


With various workers all tests of all projects are executed in parallel, aren't they? The test is executed once for each project. Hence it's not guaranteed that it won't run for two projects at the same time..? That shouldn't happen.
